# How can I solo Razorgore the Untamed?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Now that I'm level 90, I'd like to solo all of the classic raid instances. Molten Core was easy, but I'm having trouble getting started in Blackwing Lair. The first boss—[Razorgore the Untamed](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=12435)—is set up in a way that prevents zerging: if you try to kill him before all the eggs in the room are destroyed, it's an instant wipe. At the same time, there are endless waves of adds that are attempting to kill him.

With at least two people, the strategy is easy: one person controls Razorgore to break the eggs, while another person (or people) collects the adds so Razorgore stays up.

But is there a way to do this solo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible, but tricky, to do it if you happen to be:

- a hunter
- a goblin
- an engineer
- a demonology warlock

The trick is to aggro Razorgore, then jump from a ledge near the [Grethok the Controller](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=12557/grethok-the-controller) to a balcony. Once on the balcony, Razorgore will continue to attack you, but Grethok will call off the alarm, preventing adds from coming in to kill Razorgore:

[image: Screenshot demonstrating where to jump]

As long as you quickly kill Grethok and the other two orcs, and stop controlling Razorgore once you hit ~25 seconds left on the Mind Exhaustion debuff, you can destroy the eggs with impunity and take Razorgore down.

#### Hunters, Goblins, and Engineers

To jump to the balcony, you need to use:

- **Hunter:** [Disengage](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=781/disengage) to jump backwards
- **Goblin:** [Rocket Jump](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=69070)
- **Engineer:** the [Nitro Boosts](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=55016) belt tinker

The YouTuber [Shopebay1](http://www.youtube.com/user/ShopEbay1) put out two videos demonstrating the basic premise.

As a hunter with Disengage and a parachute:

As an engineer with Nitro Boosts:

Note that I found trying this with the Nitro Boosts to be extremely frustrating: you only have a few seconds, it's prone to failure, and it has a three minute cooldown, meaning if you don't make the jump it's a wipe.

#### Demonology Warlock

Demonology warlocks have it easy. Before pulling Razorgore, make the jump using [Demonic Leap](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=109151). Once on the balcony, [summon a Demonic Circle](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=48018). Then, pull Razorgore: once you're in range of the Demonic Circle, pull one of the orcs and [teleport](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=48020). Then, follow the same strategy described above and demonstrated in Shopebay1's videos.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are warriors, here's how:

What you need

1. Second Wind
2. Mocking Banner (Not mandatory if you're not 90 but makes it easier)
3. Dragons war or bladestorm (for fast aoe aggro)

Try to be as low hp as possible before entering the instance so you can get second wind up as fast as possible. Aggro the mobs by the mind control orb and immediately take control of the boss and start breaking the eggs on the other platform, this is very important as you should be able to clear that entire platform before any other mobs even spawn and save you lots of hp.

If second wind is up most mobs will get aggro from it so you can wait to use mocking banner until about 10-15 seconds after the mobs start spawning. The elite dragons don't seem to take aggro from it as much as the other mobs but you can use the bosses sleep ability on them and you can sleep more than one at a time and it doesn't have a cooldown.

Once you destroy enough eggs that you get to the middle of the room coming towards your character throw down your banner, if you did things right the boss should still be around 325k ish hp which is plenty.

A good spell talent to throw out to get aggro is disrupting shout for the casters and be sure to use thunder clap and dragons war or bladestorm when the boss has to much aggro or when you have to much mobs on you, just make sure to try to not hit the boss with your aoe as much as possible cause it will add up. At level 90 i had 340k hp which was to much combined with my armor to keep second wind up so i took off most of my gear till i had about 23k armor and 170k hp which was enough to keep second wind up 100% of the time and keep me alive.

I ended the egg part of the fight with the boss at around 125k hp. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I soloed him as both a protection Paladin (wearing mostly greens) and a Demonology Warlock (Wearing about 3 raidfinder epics and the rest rep blue's)

I'd like to help you with tactics, but I didn't really use any. On both character I controlled razorgore, and smashed many eggs, when the charm expired I killed all adds that had gathered around me, and I rinsed and repeated that about 4 times.

By doing a burst of healing/damage in the breaks, most things agro'ed to my character so Razorgore was a healthy young dragonspawn most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

What you need;

- Your maximum HP
- HoT buff
- A way to heal fast

I was an Affliction Lock for this, so try to simulate to suit your class/spec.

This evening I discovered that as I was roaming around as Razorgore the adds would hit me once and rush off to strike my character. I later discovered this was because my Grimoire of Sacrifice buff healed me for 5% every few seconds, causing healer aggro.

In fact nobody seemed to pay Razorgore any attention until my first channel ran out but by that time I only had 1/4 the eggs left and it didn't matter.

The only danger here was of my toon dying, so I popped Unending Resolve and spammed Harvest Life and carried on once my health was over half. With huge HP, armour or self heals I doubt that should be a problem for any of the *ahem* lesser classes :P

Answer (score 1):

I Tried this several times as BM Hunter using the shopebay method but died everytime. I had a look around and found a much easier method.

- Re-spec your talents for exhilaration.
- Kill all 3 Orcs immediately,
- drop ice, snake, and explosive trap quickly,
- and M/C Razorgore.

You'll get about 1/2 the eggs or so 1st time you M/C. Quickly re-drop your traps, M/C Razor 2nd time and finish off the eggs.

If you notice his health getting really low hit your Exhilaration spell and it heals him back to 100% and will pop you back out of M/C. Finish off last adds then you'll be free to take out Razor.

Exhilaration has a 2 minute cooldown so even if you don't take out the eggs quickly it should be ready to use again by the time your M/C wears off. Tried this and worked great the first time. Got the pet too.